# Creating HTML dropdown list?

Tags: html

is there any website or tool that i can give list of words about (1000 words) and generates the HTML code of the drop down list contains all the words. for example:
words: jak, jo, jhon, ...
the HTML code should be like this :

```
 <select>
<option value="jak">jak</option>
<option value="jo">jo</option>
<option value="jhon">jhon</option>
</select>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: JavaScript is a pretty good tool =)

Comment: is there any way using javascript??!!! how ??!!

Comment: Do you have a half-decent editor that supports find and replace using regular expressions?

Comment: Using an array, a loop and string concatenation.

Comment: i have notbad++ and netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have each word on one line, open the list in Notepad++ and run a find and replace on it in regular expression mode.

Find:

```
([\w-]+)
```

Replace with:

```
<option value="\1">\1</option>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I was quite happy to learn this but it doesn't seem to work in Notepad++ v6.1.2
It just replaced every line with `<option value=""></option>`. Is there anything else required apart from the full regex mode?

Comment: @Tom: Hah, I actually forgot the parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: Now this will come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is definetly possible in Javascript.  I don't think a website is necessary here. Is the list of names stored in an array? If so, you can do something like this:

```
<select>

<script type="text/javascript">
     for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
         document.write('<option value="'+names[i]+'">'+names[i]+'</option>')
     }
</script>

</select>
```

Let me know if that's not what you want.

Comment: `document.write` is bad and creating HTML in JavaScript is bad and you’re missing a brace.

Comment: I added the brace back. I know document.write is bad but this guy doesn't seem like the most profficient JS programmer. Does he want the Angular solution?

Comment: If people keep feeding him things that they know are bad, he’s hardly going to become more proficient…

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create it with JavaScript & jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var words = "jak,jo,jhon";
            var wordsArray = words.split(',');

            for(var i = 0, len = wordsArray; i < len; i++) {
                $('select').append('<option>' + wordsArray[i] + '</option>');
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select />
</body>
```

Comment: No, that’s how to create it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ArdVp/

```
/* comma separated list of words */
var wordList = 'jak,jo,jhon';
var html = '';

var wordArray = wordList.split(",");
html += '<select>';
for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    html += '<option value="' + wordArray[i] + '">' + wordArray[i] + '</option>';
}
html += '</select>';

alert(html);
```